# How to Minimize the surface area of a solid of revolution of a constant volume?

Tags: integration, area, volume, solid-of-revolution

I read this post here however, I want to know whether it would be possible to minimize the
surface area of a solid of revolution which is a non catenary.
[Catenary curve for minimum surface of revolution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2114630/catenary-curve-for-minimum-surface-of-revolution)

It is a 4 degree equation of
-1.8*10^-4*x^4 + 6.521*10^-3*x^3-7.288*10^-2*x^2 + 2.53*10^-1*x + 2.775

it has a Surface area of 390 cm^2 and volume of 500cm^2

How do I minimize the surface area used while retaining the same volume?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Since you’re giving us the equation of the profile curve, the shape is fixed, and so are the area and volume — there’s nothing to vary, so minimizing is impossible.

Comment: So you are saying that I won't be able to find the shape that gives the minimum surface area while retaining the same volume?

Comment: What about dividing it into frustums, then minimising that?

Comment: Again, if the equation is fixed (your 4th degree equation), then the shape is fixed, not variable, so the volume and surface area are fixed. If you want to minimize, there has to be some paramter that we can tweak in order to make the surface area smaller. What is the parameter that we’re allowed to tweak??

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more on that? examples or something? Initially, the shape is fixed however, I don't mind the shape. I only want to mathematically find any shape with a volume of 500cm^3 that takes the smallest surface area as possible.

Comment: If we’re allowed to ignore the 4th degree equation you gave, then the shape with minimal surface area is a sphere.

Comment: And what would be the best way to derive that?

Comment: The isoperimetric inequality states that a sphere has the smallest surface area for a  given volume https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality#In_%7F'%22%60UNIQ--postMath-00000019-QINU%60%22'%7F

Comment: That’s why soap bubbles are spherical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, it seems that we’re allowed to ignore the 4th degree equation that was given. Apparently, the OP just wants to find a shape with minimal surface area that has a volume of 500 cm^3.

The [isoperimetric inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality#In_%7F%27%22%60UNIQ--postMath-00000019-QINU%60%22%27%7F) states that a sphere has the smallest surface area for a given volume. That’s why soap bubbles are spherical. The radius of the desired sphere can be found by solving for $r$ in the equation $\tfrac43 \pi r^3 = 500$.

Comment: I get it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can consider a *toy* problem to see how this would work. Consider a right circular cylinder of radius $r$ and height $h$. We then have

$$
V=\pi r^2h\\
S=2\pi rh+2\pi r^2
$$

Thus, we can express

$$
S=\frac{2\pi V}{\pi r}+2\pi r^2\\
\frac{S}{V}=2\left(\frac{1}{r}+\frac{\pi r^2}{V} \right)
$$

We can minimize $S/V$ with respect to $r$,

$$
\frac{\partial (S/V)}{\partial r}=2\left(-\frac{1}{r^2}+\frac{2\pi r}{V} \right)=0\\
r=\sqrt[3]{\frac{V}{2\pi}}\\
h=\frac{V}{\pi r^2}
$$

As an example, let $V=2\pi$ so that by the above $r=1$ and $h=2$. Then $S=2\pi rh+2\pi r^2=6\pi$.

Suppose now that $r=1/2$. Then $h=8,\ V=2\pi$ and $S=17\pi/2$. For $r=2$ we get $h=1,\ V=2\pi$, and $S=12\pi$.

Comment: Your answer was useful but I am looking for any shape that can help minimize SA but thanks anyway!!